# Duke deduplication engine: How to create HBase as the custom data source?

Tags: hbase

As per duke documentation (https://github.com/larsga/Duke/wiki/Datasources), a custom datasource can be create using:

```
<data-source class="class name here">
    <param name="bean property" value="value"/>
    ...
</data-source>
```

I need help in creating Hbase as the custom datasource.

Comment: i didn't use duke before but, if you check the source you can see there is no implementation of hbase as the custom data source, looks like you can implement it by extending ColumnarDataSource or if you can connect hbase with jdbc , you can use JDBC Data source which is built-in datasource of duke .